# Showing current employers work on own website?

Tags: ethics, portfolio

I want to create a portfolio website and show potential employers the websites I have made at my current job. But, hosting company code without their permission is unethical, so what should I do to show them my work?

Comment: See also: [Applying for jobs, new company wants to see source code that I don't have access to any more](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57990/applying-for-jobs-new-company-wants-to-see-source-code-that-i-dont-have-access)

Comment: If your employer's websites are publicly available then have you considered posting links to them instead?

Answer (score 2):

Is there anyway you could take screenshots of the finished product?

^If this is still a violation of your company policy, I would create different work samples. The last thing you want to do is get in trouble with your current company.

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search for: [web design company](http://www.google.com/search?q=web%20design%20company)

Many company/designers showcase direct links to the public websites that they have built. Where showcasing your work becomes an issue is if the design was meant for internal use only.